# Updating dataitem in parent row of hierarchical kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui-grid

Im trying to update a few fields of the parent row in a hierarchical grid.  The child row fields seem to update fine, but not the parent.

```
var testVal = 11.11;
var childGrid = $('#SomePayments_' + paymentId).data('kendoGrid');
var childRow = $(e).closest('tr');
var childData = childGrid.dataItem(childRow);

childData.OrderLevel = "A";
//childGrid.refresh();

// Get reference to parent row and payment data.
var detailRow = childRow.closest('div');
var parentRow = detailRow.closest('tr').prev()[0];
var paymentData = $("#PaymentsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(parentRow);


paymentData.ShortageAmt = testVal;
paymentData.UpstartAmt = testVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to call the refresh on the grid after setting the dataItem.

```
var grid = $("#PaymentsGrid").data("kendoGrid")
var paymentData = grid.dataItem(parentRow);

paymentData.ShortageAmt = testVal;
grid.refresh();
```